# Parsing Generator Python 2

Tags: python, parsing, generator, yield

Input:

```
@example1
abcd
efg
hijklmnopq
@example2
123456789
```

Script:

```
def parser_function(f):
    name = ''
    body = ''   
    for line in f:  
        if len(line) >= 1:
            if line[0] == '@':
                name = line  
                continue 
            body = body + line  
            yield name,''.join(body)

for line in parser_function(data_file):
    print line
```

Output

```
('@example1', 'abcd')
('@example1', 'abcdefg')
('@example1', 'abcdefghijklmnopq')
('@example2', 'abcdefghijklmnopq123456789')
```

Desired Output:

```
('@example1', 'abcdefghijklmnopq')
('@example2', '123456789')
```

My problem, my generator is yielding every line but i'm not sure where to reset the line. i'm having trouble getting the desired output and i've tried a few different ways.  any help would be greatly appreciated. saw some other generators that had "if name:" but they were fairly complicated.  I got it to work using those codes but i'm trying to make my code as small as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change where you `yield`:

```
def parser_function(f):
    name = None
    body = ''    
    for line in f:  
        if line and line[0] == '@':
            if name:
                yield name, body
            name = line
        else:
            body += line  
    if name:
        yield name, body
```

This `yield`s once before every `@...` and once at the end.

P.S. I've renamed `str` to `body` to avoid shadowing a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: might be worth pointing out not to use `str` as a variable name

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Good point, let me add this to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: what is the "if line and line[0] == '@'"  I understand the line[0] but wouldn't the "if line" always be True?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: In essence, `if line` checks whether the line is not empty (so that we don't try to do `line[0]` on an empty line).